# Create a method for a long click or pressed Button in javafx

Tags: class, javafx, click, long-integer, pressed

In my program I need to make an action when a button is long pressed/click. So I decided to create a method which gets the button in its parameters and return a boolean when the button click is longer than 1 second :

```
public class EventOperations {

JFXButton button;
boolean result = false;

// Button long click
public EventOperations(JFXButton btn) {
    button = btn;
}

public void isLongPressed() {

    final AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

    private long lastUpdate = 0;

    @Override
    public void handle(long time) {
        if (this.lastUpdate > 2000000000) {
            result = true;
            System.out.println("PRESSED !!!!!!!!!");
        }
        this.lastUpdate = time;
    }
    };

    button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });

}

public boolean getIsPressed() {
    return result;
}
```

}

MAIN.JAVA

```
EventOperations buttonPressed = new EventOperations(jfxButtonFolder);
buttonPressed.isLongPressed();
```

But everytime I clicked quickly on the button it shows several "PRESSED !!!" so it doesn't work. The number of 2000000000 is an example.
**What can I do to get the boolean in my main java method and if it's "pressed" call a function to do something ?**

**EDIT ! It's work perfectly thank you !**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about just use the start and end times:

```
button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        long startTime;

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 2 * 1000) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed for at least 2 seconds (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds)");
                } else
                    System.out.println("Pressed for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `time` parameter of the `handle` method in [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) is the **timestamp** of the current frame given in nanoseconds. As such, you shouldn't be setting `lastUpdate` to this value and comparing it with your desired mouse hold interval.

You should be recording the timestamp when the mouse was clicked in the parameter `lastUpdate` and the `handle` event should be checking the difference between the current time and and `lastUpdate` to see if it is greater than your mouse hold interval.

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
public void isLongPressed() {

    final AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

    private long lastUpdate = 0;

    @Override
    public void handle(long time) {
        if (Instant.now() - lastUpdate > 2000000000) {
            result = true;
            System.out.println("PRESSED !!!!!!!!!");
        }
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        lastUpdate = Instant.now(); // Assuming you are using Java 9
    }
    };

    button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
}
```